# JSF: Empty space caused by rendered attribute

Tags: jsf, rendered-attribute

How can I get rid of the empty space by components not rendered via rendered attribute?

I want to display a list of objects in a dataTable and sort them by a property they have. I do it likes this:
view plaincopy to clipboardprint?

```
<t:dataTable value="#{someBean.values}" var="value">  
    <h:column>  
        <f:facet name="header">  
            <t:outputText value="X" />  
        </f:facet>  
        <h:panelGroup rendered="#{value.property eq 'X'}">  
          <!-- some stuff -->  
        </h:panelGroup>  
    </h:column>  
    <h:column>  
        <f:facet name="header">  
            <t:outputText value="Y" />  
        </f:facet>  
        <h:panelGroup rendered="#{value.property eq 'Y'}">  
          <!-- some stuff -->  
        </h:panelGroup>  
    </h:column>                 
</t:dataTable>
```

It will display one item every row only, because of the rendered thingy. How can I avoid this? I stumpled upon this also on other occasions...

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a single column and render in there.

```
<t:dataTable value="#{someBean.values}" var="value">  
    <h:column>  
        <f:facet name="header">  
            <t:outputText value="#{value.property}" />  
        </f:facet>  
        <h:panelGroup rendered="#{value.property eq 'X'}">  
          <!-- some stuff -->  
        </h:panelGroup>  
        <h:panelGroup rendered="#{value.property eq 'Y'}">  
          <!-- some stuff -->  
        </h:panelGroup>  
    </h:column>                 
</t:dataTable>
```

Comment: As usual: Thanks for being kind enough to share your vast knowledge!

Answer (score 2):

It is obvious to display one item every row with `datatable`.

You can better have two different datatables, one rendering for x and other rendering for y and adjust your `css` accordingly that looks like two column of the same table. Or else using [richfaces](http://richfaces-showcase.appspot.com/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=dataTable&skin=blueSky), `<rich:subTable>` would help you, such as having two `subTable` in a single `dataTable`

Comment: Thank you! I will go for the two dataTables method, I think.